# Recyclerview with different type

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Hi guys I'm trying to populate `RecyclverView` with different collections.. For example I got 2 list lets say customer list and supplier list.

What I want to achieve is :

- customer header

---

- Customer 1
- Customer 2

---

- supplier header

---

- Supplier 1
- Supplier 2

Is that possible? Thanks.
Sorry for my English

Comment: You could override this method [getItemViewType()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type) in your adapter;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do this with `RecyclerView`, you should override `getItemViewType()` method.

Like this:

```
private class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int TYPE_1 = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_2 = 2;
    private static final int TYPE_3 = 3;
    // more types...

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case TYPE_1:
                break;
            case TYPE_2:
                break;
            case TYPE_3:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case TYPE_1:
                break;
            case TYPE_2:
                break;
            case TYPE_3:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position == 1) {
            return TYPE_1;
        } else if(position == 2) {
            return TYPE_2;
        } else 
            return TYPE_3
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make Section in recyclerview like this way

```
public class MainAdapter extends SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter<MainAdapter.MainVH> {

    @Override
    public int getSectionCount() {
        return 20; // number of sections.
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(int section) {
        return 8; // number of items in section (section index is parameter).
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(MainVH holder, int section) {
        // Setup header view.
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MainVH holder, int section, int relativePosition, int absolutePosition) {
        // Setup non-header view.
        // 'section' is section index.
        // 'relativePosition' is index in this section.
        // 'absolutePosition' is index out of all non-header items.
        // See sample project for a visual of how these indices work.
    }

    @Override
    public MainVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Change inflated layout based on 'header'. 
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_HEADER ? R.layout.header : R.layout.normal, parent, false);
        return new MainVH(v);
    }

    public static class MainVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public MainVH(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // Setup view holder.
            // You'd want some views to be optional, e.g. for header vs. normal.
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/afollestad/sectioned-recyclerview

https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter

https://gist.github.com/afollestad/c84e259e98a03134dfd5